# Python - Error in two-layer neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to implement a 2-layer neural network from scratch. But there is something wrong. After some iterations, my loss becomes `nan`.

```
'''
We are implementing a two layer neural network.
'''
import numpy as np

x,y = np.random.rand(64,1000),np.random.randn(64,10)
w1,w2 = np.random.rand(1000,100),np.random.rand(100,10)
learning_rate = 1e-4
x -= np.mean(x,axis=0) #Normalizing the Training Data Set

for t in range(2000):
  h = np.maximum(0,x.dot(w1))    # Applying Relu Non linearity
  ypred = h.dot(w2) #Output of Hidden layer

  loss = np.square(ypred - y).sum()
  print('Step',t,'\tLoss:- ',loss)

  #Gradient Descent

  grad_ypred = 2.0 * (ypred - y)
  gradw2 = (h.transpose()).dot(grad_ypred)
  grad_h = grad_ypred.dot(w2.transpose())
  gradw1 = (x.transpose()).dot(grad_h*h*(1-h))

  w1 -= learning_rate*gradw1
  w2 -= learning_rate*gradw2
```

I also implemented Linear Regression using a Softmax classifier and multi-class SVM loss. Same problem happens. Please tell me how to resolve this.

Output:

```
D:\Study Material\Python 3 Tutorial\PythonScripts\Machine Learning>python TwoLayerNeuralNet.py
Step 0  Loss:-  19436393.79233052
Step 1  Loss:-  236820315509427.38
Step 2  Loss:-  1.3887002186558748e+47
Step 3  Loss:-  1.868219503527502e+189
Step 4  Loss:-  inf
TwoLayerNeuralNet.py:23: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  gradw1 = (x.transpose()).dot(grad_h*h*(1-h))
TwoLayerNeuralNet.py:12: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in maximum
  h = np.maximum(0,x.dot(w1))    # Applying Relu Non linearity
Step 5  Loss:-  nan
Step 6  Loss:-  nan
Step 7  Loss:-  nan
Step 8  Loss:-  nan
Step 9  Loss:-  nan
Step 10         Loss:-  nan
Step 11         Loss:-  nan
Step 12         Loss:-  nan
Step 13         Loss:-  nan
Step 14         Loss:-  nan
Step 15         Loss:-  nan
Step 16         Loss:-  nan
Step 17         Loss:-  nan
Step 18         Loss:-  nan
Step 19         Loss:-  nan
Step 20         Loss:-  nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your loss is becoming too high
try this

```
loss = np.square(ypred - y).mean()
```

and if still doesn't work try reducing the learning rate to something like `1e-8`.
and observe if the loss is going up or down, if loss is reducing thats good, if the loss is increasing thats a bad sign, you might want to consider using a better dataset and check the weights updation.

Comment: although my implementation is correct though right sir?

Comment: Sorry sir its not working though: First loss is increasing and after some iterations its becoming nan and also overflow error is showing in square,and multiply operation